# Exercise question pertaining to Unions and Intersections of 3 sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[image]

I have spent a day and a half trying to answer this question.

I do not know how to prove that C is a subset of A using the given equality.

Comment: Prove the double inclusion: $(A \cap B) \cup C \subseteq A \cap (B \cup C)$ and vice versa...

Comment: you do not need to prove that the condition "C subset A" is independent of B. All it means is that "C subset A" says nothing about B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use, that $C \subset A \Leftrightarrow A \cup C  = A$ and then simplify, for example, first member:
$$(A \cap B) \cup C = (A \cup C) \cap (B \cup C) $$

Comment: Look, please, that it is equivalency $C \subset A \Leftrightarrow A \cup C  = A$ in answer, so you can use both sides of equality in both directions.

Comment: I prefer to formulate it in following way: C is subset of A if and only if (is equivalent) union of A with C equals A.

Answer (score 0):

**Just a visual**
[image]
$(A\cap B)\cup C=A\cap(B\cup C)\Leftrightarrow$Area of $475=$ Area of $47536\Leftrightarrow$ Area $36=0\Leftrightarrow C-C\cap A=0\Leftrightarrow C=C\cap A\Leftrightarrow C\subset A$.

Note that "necessary and sufficient" implies use of $\Leftrightarrow$.